# Comparing 2 data frame with different size

Tags: r

I would like to check if the values in my dataframe df is larger than the threshold in df2. I tried making df2 to have the size with df to test on the threshold, but is an alternate way to do this?

```
    > df
    A     B     C
    5    12    -5
    4     4     0
   15     5     9
    1    11     1
   11     1    -3

   > df2 
   A     B     C
   5     6     3
```

I tried replicating df2 into and then checking if `df > df2`

```
  > df2
   A     B     C
   5     6     3
   5     6     3
   5     6     3
   5     6     3
   5     6     3
```

dput

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(A = c(5, 4, 15, 1, 11), B = c(12, 4, 5, 11, 1), 
C = c(-5, 0, 9, 1, -3)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

> dput(df2)
structure(list(A = 5, B = 6, C = 3), row.names = c(NA, -1L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using `sweep` :

```
sweep(df, 2, unlist(df2), `>`)

#         A     B     C
#[1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
#[3,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#[4,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#[5,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the follwing code

```
setNames(data.frame(do.call("cbind",lapply(names(df), function(nam) {
  df[[nam]] > df2[[nam]]
}))),names(df))

#      A     B     C
#1 FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#2 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#3  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
#4 FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#5  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

If its enough to get the result as named matrix (coercing to `data.frame` is quite time consuming if not really needed), you can just do:

```
  comparedMatrix <- do.call("cbind",lapply(names(df), function(nam) {
    df[[nam]] > df2[[nam]]
  }))
  colnames(comparedMatrix) <- names(df)
  comparedMatrix
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), ~ . > df2[[cur_column()]]))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  A     B     C    
#  <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
#1 FALSE TRUE  FALSE
#2 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#3 TRUE  FALSE TRUE 
#4 FALSE TRUE  FALSE
#5 TRUE  FALSE FALSE
```

---

Or using `map2`

```
library(purrr)
map2_df(df, df2, `>`)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  A     B     C    
#  <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
#1 FALSE TRUE  FALSE
#2 FALSE FALSE FALSE
#3 TRUE  FALSE TRUE 
#4 FALSE TRUE  FALSE
#5 TRUE  FALSE FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R option using `t` + `unlist`

```
> t(t(df)> unlist(df2))
         A     B     C
[1,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[4,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[5,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```